# Generate pie chart reports/cucumber framework reports from robotframework testcases

Tags: robotframework

Is there a way using Robot Framework Testcases Where I can generate reports in the piechart format.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Which language are you using? If you are using Python, you can import Pylab and introduce your own keyword that generates a piechart. But I do not think the current robot framework generates a piechart for you.